Color conditional formating with two parameters in Pine Script
Tried to create bgcolor formating with two parameters, but getting error. Would someone fix the problem.
Further, wish to know How to do color formating when table.cell_set_text() is used.
//Delta Table

Table_Def = table.new(position = position.bottom_right, columns = 30, rows = 1, frame_color = color.black, frame_width = 1, border_color = color.black, border_width = 1)

table.cell(Table_Def, column = 0, row = 2, text = "CumDelta", text_color = color.black, text_size = size.auto, text_halign = text.align_left)

table.cell(Table_Def, column = 1, row = 2, text = str.tostring(cumdelta\[29\]), text_color = color.black, bgcolor = if cumdelta\[29\]\>0 and cumdelta\[29\]\>cvdAverage\[29\] \* 1.05 ? color.new(color.lime, 0) : if cumdelta\[29\]\>0 and cumdelta\[29\]\>cvdAverage\[29\] \* 1.025 ? color.new(color.lime, 50) : if cumdelta\[29\]\<0 and cumdelta\[29\]\<cvdAverage\[29\]\*1.05) ? color.new(color.fuchsia, 0) : if cumdelta\[29\]\<0 and cumdelta\[29\]\<cvdAverage\[29\]\*1.05) ? color.new(color.fuchsia, 50) : color.new(color.gray, 50), text_size = size.auto, text_halign = text.align_right)


the ternary does not need "if"
try this:
//Delta Table

Table_Def = table.new(position = position.bottom_right, columns = 30, rows = 1, frame_color = color.black, frame_width = 1, border_color = color.black, border_width = 1)

table.cell(Table_Def, column = 0, row = 2, text = "CumDelta", text_color = color.black, text_size = size.auto, text_halign = text.align_left)

cumdeltaCol = cumdelta > 0 and cumdelta > cvdAverage * 1.05  ? color.new(color.lime, 0)     :
              cumdelta > 0 and cumdelta > cvdAverage * 1.025 ? color.new(color.lime, 50)    :
              cumdelta < 0 and cumdelta < cvdAverage * 1.05  ? color.new(color.fuchsia, 0)  :
              cumdelta < 0 and cumdelta < cvdAverage * 1.05  ? color.new(color.fuchsia, 50) :
              color.new(color.gray, 50)

table.cell(Table_Def, column = 1, row = 2, text = str.tostring(cumdelta), text_color = color.black, bgcolor = cumdeltaCol, text_size = size.auto, text_halign = text.align_right)


Thank you for sparing time in answering the query. I created a table for Delta, cumDelta etc. for 30 bar candles assinging the lookback bar numbers.  It worked. Thank you once again
